# How to make my scrollable horizontal gallery centered on the first of three images and be responsive using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image-gallery

I'm creating a portfolio and have a horizontally scrolling gallery with 3 macbook screenshots of some personal projects of mine. My bootstrap knowledge is limited, so I could use some help.

First, I want it to center the scrolling on the first image in the gallery. How do I accomplish this? Having trouble because the edge of the second image is always in view.

Second, I want to make the gallery responsive and still center on the first project picture. Not sure how to accomplish this.

FYI, I do plan on creating a modal for each image that contains relevant case study material for each project.

Thanks in advance!

HTML

```
 <!-- Work Section -->
<section id="work" class="container content-section text-center">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="gallery horizontal-gallery">
            <img class="work-modals" src="http://madebymunsters.github.io/Lannister/img/blocitoff.png">
            <img class="work-modals" src="http://madebymunsters.github.io/Lannister/img/blocitoff.png">
            <img class="work-modals" src="http://madebymunsters.github.io/Lannister/img/blocitoff.png">
        </div>                    
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.gallery {
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.gallery .horizontal-gallery {
    display: inline;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/QJ16EUgEVf

Answer (score 0):

You can try this http://www.bootply.com/TVthEnxmzd

Wrap each image with div and make it 100% width and display:inline-block;